# "Syntax error: operand expected ..." in script that was working right

Tags: bash, shell

I had a script that was doing well until now, I don't now what has changed, but the script is the same.

I had this variables:

```
SIZEKB=$[[(SIZE+1023)/1024]]
REQUIREDKB=$[[SIZEKB+MINFREEKB]]
```

Which I repeat were working ok, but now I got this error:

```
line 12: [(SIZE+1023)/1024]: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "[(SIZE+1023)/1024]")
line 13: [SIZEKB+MINFREEKB]: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "[SIZEKB+MINFREEKB]")
```

What should I change to correct the syntax, thanks!

Comment: What is `$[]`?  Normally you'd use `$((...))` for arithmetic expansion.

Comment: @Shawn bash also recognizes `$[expr]`. See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2010-03/msg00083.html

Comment: But here it is `$[[ ]]` not `$[ ]`. Might that be the problem? However, I don't know why this script used to work (did it really?) and now doesn't anymore. Maybe a version update? Maybe a switch to another shell?

Comment: @AndresChandia : I am pretty sure that **this** code never executed correctly.

Comment: @user1934428 Working correctly for years... the script is found in http://mldonkey.sourceforge.net/File_completed_cmd where it says **Dispatching completed files to several directories**

Comment: Whoever posted this, did not try it.You won't find an official _bash_ version, which supports this. Even the single-bracket variant `$[...]` is still supported, although the use is discuraged due to obsolescence. I have the impression that the code on this page is from different authors, because the programming style differs in the various parts. In any case, wrong is worong, so you have to fix it in your copy .....

Comment: @AndrésChandía : If you really want to research in this area, you could ask at [bash mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/bug-bash) whether someone knows about some old bash version that indeed experimentally had `$[[...]]` as a feature. If you are lucky, this is still present as a hidden feature and needs to be reactivated somehow before we can use it, perhaps by setting some undocumented switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to write those assignment is to providean arithmetic context:

```
((SIZEKB=(SIZE+1023)/1024))
((REQUIREDKB=SIZEKB+MINFREEKB))
```

You **can** use also

```
SIZEKB=$[(SIZE+1023)/1024]
REQUIREDKB=$[SIZEKB+MINFREEKB]
```

but this is deprecated and provided for compatibility with old scripts (perhaps those written for bash version 1?).

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the equations in two curly brackets and so:

```
REQUIREDKB=$(( $SIZEKB+$MINFREEKB ))
```

Alternatively, you can use single square brackets and so:

```
REQUIREDKB=$[ $SIZEKB+$MINFREEKB ]
```